# ARM Platform Compilation Error

Tags: arm

I am trying to compile the NAS NPB benchmarks on ARM 64 platform running
Ubuntu 14.04, using MVAPICH 2.1. I keep getting an error

> "**/usr/bin/ld: ../common/print_results.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
>       /usr/bin/ld: ../common/print_results.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
>       ../common/print_results.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format**
>       "

While trying to compile these benchmarks using `mpif77` and `mpicc`. Can anybody help me resolve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried some variety of `-fPIC`/`-pie` compilation flags?

Comment: That's not a compiler error, it's a linker error. How did you build that file? Do you expect it to match your other object files?